# Project to remove field from dynamically-named subdocument

Tags: regex, mongodb, search, wildcard

I have db struct like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a702c1434ddce0015a9fc2b"),
    "create_on_fmt" : "20180130082556",
    "create_on" : ISODate("2018-01-30T08:25:56.222Z"),
    "type" : 1,
    "code" : "3YFZZ",
    "handled_by" : {
            "644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b" : {
                    "email" : "abca@email.com",
                    "update_on" : ISODate("2018-02-05T15:43:59.612Z"),
                    "update_on_fmt" : "20180205154359"
            }
    }
}
```

How i can return result without `handled_by.XXX.update_on` when `644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b` is auto gen and have value not exactly?

I had tried `db.test.find({"code" : "3YFZZ"}, {'handled_by./%/.update_on':0}).pretty()` but not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to be able to use $project on this property (discarding it) and then reverse operation which is [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get back original shape. Try this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            handled_by: {
                $objectToArray: "$handled_by"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "handled_by.v.update_on": 0
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            handled_by: {
                $arrayToObject: "$handled_by"
            }
        }
    }
])
```